# I do have more than 10 points of reputation on this site - 103 currently. How can I add an answer?

Tags: bug, answers, reputation, protected-questions

This question is protected: [My 13-year-old son made a foolish and wasteful donation. How can I teach him he was wrong?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/20283/my-13-year-old-son-made-a-foolish-and-wasteful-donation-how-can-i-teach-him-he)

I do have more than 10 points reputation on this site - 103 currently, so why is it that I can not add an answer?

I have more reputation on other sites, but that's irrelevant.
The 103 include the joining bonus I got on this site, which is indicating a minimum of default reputation, on this site - not anywhere else.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238082/unable-to-answer-protected-question-despite-having-enough-reputation

Answer (score 1):

The number you need to have earned on this site excludes the joining bonus, as it was earned from other sites.

So you have 3 earned on this site - not enough yet.

In order to improve your rep while you cannot answer, try improving your existing posts.

Comment: But it's clearly about the reputation I have here, so the description is wrong, right? ("Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality answers, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site.") If the bonus is not indicating reputation, what is it's meaning? If joining here would increase reputation where I came from, I would get the points there.

Comment: The bonus is earned from your activity on other sites, not on this site.

Comment: Yes, sure, that's the point - that a user can get enough reputation to just assume a minimum reputation elsewhere. The bonus should mean the same as reputation, as it is representet as a fraction of reputation. Why not requiering 110 points, and accepting the bonus as vsalid?

Comment: The way it is written is admittedly unclear, but Rory correctly described how it works (and I'll note this is not a Parenting-specific restriction, either).

Comment: It isn't the same as elsewhere. Rep earned on a site about English may have no relevance to a site about Music, for example. The 100 bonus is an assumption you have learned a bit about how to use stack exchange